# Extending homeomorphism of the boundary of a disk to the whole disk

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Here, disk refers any space homeomorphic to the closed unit disk.

Let $A$ be a disk. Then by definition, there is a homeomorphism $h:A\to D$. A homeomorphism $g:\delta A\to \delta A$ is given. (Here, $\delta A:= h^{-1}(C),$ where $C$ is the boundary circle of the disk.)

$f:=hgh^{-1}:C\to C$ can be extended to the whole $D$ as follows:

$f(x):=hgh^{-1}(x)=\begin{cases}0, x=0\\\|x\| hgh^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{\|x\|}\right) , x\in D-\{ 0\}\end{cases}$.

If $f$ is proven to be continuous, then it would follow by compactness and Hausdorfness of $D$, that $f$ is a homeomorphism.

Pasting lemma doesn't work here as $\{0\}$ is closed and $D-\{0\}$ is open so let's use the definition:

Take any open set $U\subset D$.

Case $1): 0\in U$

$f^{-1}(U)=\{0\}\bigcup \{x\in D-\{0\}: \|x\|hgh^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{\|x\|}\right)\in U-\{0\}\}$, the second set here is an open set as $x\mapsto \|x\|f\left(\frac{x}{\|x\|}\right)$ is continuous, hence $f^{-1}(U)$ is a union of a closed set with an open set.

Case $2):0\not\in U$

$f^{-1}(U)=\{x\in D-\{0\}: \|x\|hgh^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{\|x\|}\right)\in U-\{0\}\}$, which is open.

**How to conclude that $f^{-1}(U)$ in case $1)$ is open?**

Once this is done, then $f$ is continuous and therefore $h^{-1}f h$ gives the desired homeomorphic extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Case 1), $U$ is open and $0 \in U$, so that $\Delta(0,\epsilon) \subset U$ for some $0 < \epsilon < 1$.

Now consider in this case your set $\{x\in D-\{0\}: \|x\|hgh^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{\|x\|}\right)\in U-\{0\}\}$.

Notice that $\Delta^{\ast}(0,\epsilon) = \Delta(0,\epsilon) \setminus \{0 \}$ must in fact be contained in this set, because $hgh^{-1}(\frac{x}{||x||})$ is some point on $\partial D$ (i.e. with norm equal to $1$), so that any point $x \in \Delta^{\ast}(0,\epsilon)$ will be such that $||x|| hgh^{-1}(\frac{x}{||x||})$ has norm less than $\epsilon$, and will thus be in $U$.

Thus $\{0 \}$ union this set is open at $0$, which is what you wanted to conclude (the latter set is open already).

Answer (score 1):

Since $h$ maps into $D$ we have $|f(x) |\le \|x\|$. This gives continuity at $0$. Continuity at other points follows from the fact that composition of continuous maps is continuous.

Comment: Thank you so much :-). Could you please also help me understand why the definition is not giving me the desired conclusion?

Comment: Thanks for the addition. I'm afraid I don't understand why $0=\|x\|\color{red}{hgh^{-1}(\frac{x}{\|x\|})}$ for some $x\in D-\{0\}$. The red part is always positive because it maps $C$ to $C$ so the only way the product can be $0$ is iff $x=0$.

Comment: @Koro Union of $\{0\}$ and an open subset of $D\setminus \{0\}$ can be open in $D$. So there is no contradiction, but it is not obvious to me why the union in your proof is necessarily open.  It is much easier to use sequential continuity.

Comment: I like your answer, it gives the desired conclusion in one go. Thanks a lot. :-)

Comment: This answer is essentially why that union of sets is open BTW